# Passing a type argument to get a list of objects implementing that type

Tags: c#, types, casting, xna, monogame

Been struggling with this for a while and this is the closest I've gotten. I'm trying to implement a component system for a game with the idea that components implement interfaces, and any game actor, which is mainly just a container for components, will implement those same interfaces and pass the method calls related to a certain interface to *all* components implementing that interface. Here's what I wrote:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a list of all objects implementing an interface 
/// </summary>
public List<IComponent> Implementing(Type t)
{
    List<IComponent> imps = new List<IComponent>();

    foreach (IComponent comp in Ancillary)
        if (comp.GetType() == t)
            imps.Add(comp);

    return imps;
}

/// <summary>
/// Draw all objects implementing IDrawDepth
/// </summary>
public void Draw(SpriteBatch batch, Vector2 spin)
{
    foreach (IDrawDepth drawable in Implementing(IDrawDepth))
    {
        drawable.Draw(batch, spin);
    }
}
```

Which throws the error

```
'IDrawDepth' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
```

Why is it acceptable to specify a Type argument if I can't actually pass one? 
Sorry I couldn't figure this out on my own, but I'm pretty stumped, and I've been looking around online. Thanks for reading.

Comment: `Implementing(typeof(IDrawDepth))` will fix your compile error.

Comment: @itsme86 I think your answer doesn't satisfy the requirement. Actually he needs to find which are the classes that implement the Interface IDrawDepth in the project.

Comment: no, that actually did it @itsme86! Thank you. I was using typeof in the Implementing() method without success. I need to do some more research on types, clearly, but you got me out of this one.